# Scope e IIFE em JS

Tags: javascript

O pessoal tudo bem? Estou aqui com uma dúvida num pequeno código, basicamente tenho um for loop que adicionar um evento click a cada numero onde será apresentado o numero que foi clicado no alert, e é claro que o número apresentado é sempre o último, até ai percebi, mas estou com uma dificuldade em entender o scope que foi acrescentado ao codigo, entendo que no inner-scope temos acesso a variaveis do outer-scope mas não o inverso, mas mesmo assim não entendo a técnica que é aplicada aqui, espero que me possam ajudar a entender:

```
var nums = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
var num = nums[i];
elem.addEventListener('click', (function(numCopy) {
    return function() {
        alert(numCopy)
    };
})(num));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tentarei explicar o que acontece no código.
O primeiro ponto que vale notar é o "Declaration Hoisting":
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Hoisting
Que significa a elevação das declarações de variáveis para o topo do escopo, que pode ser global ou de função. Ou seja:

```
for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++)
```

É como fazer:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
```

Desta forma a variável i estará disponível para uso por todos dentro do escopo.

E por este motivo que ao adicionar um clique desta forma:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(nums[i])
});
```

Resultará sempre no último número sendo exibido. Pois a função anônima que você criou tem acesso às variáveis i e nums  que foram no mesmo escopo da função anônima. Significando que, no momento em que a função é executada a variável i contém o índice do último elemento do Array.

### IIFE

Para mitigar este problema, usamos uma IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), uma função que se executa imediatamente ao ser criada. Geralmente expressa desta forma:

```
(function(){

}())
```

Ou

```
(function(){

})()
```

Embora eu, pessoalmente, prefira a primeira opção. Ao fazer o que você demonstra no código, o seguinte acontece:

1. A IFFE é executada *durante* o loop e recebe como parâmetro o valor contido no índice atual do Array;

   ```
   elem.addEventListener('click', (function(num) {

   })(nums[i]));
   ```
2. Como uma nova função foi declarada, um novo escopo é criado. Este escopo tem uma variável chamada *num* que contém o valor contido no índice do array com que a função foi chamada.
3. Você retorna uma nova função que ao ser executada chamará a função alert, passando num como parâmetro;

   ```
   return function() {
     alert(num);
   };
   ```
4. Esta nova função, que foi criada na cláusula *return* é então adicionada como listener do evento;

   ```
   elem.addEventListener('click', (function(num) {
      return function() {
        alert(num)
      };
   })(nums[i]));
   ```

No seu caso, ao clicar é exibido sempre o último número do Array porquê, pelo que eu entendi, você chama o addEventListener várias vezes no mesmo elemento. Sendo assim, ao adicionar um novo listener, o antigo é sobrescrito.