# Erro Closure on a variable in loop of outer scope

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação aonde recebo uma lista de empresas e suas localização (latitude e longitude), então eu tenho que plotar todas essas localizações no `Google Maps`, o meu problema e ao tentar adicionar um `listner` para capturar o click nesses markers e então abrir uma `infoWindow`.

Meu código:

```
empresaMark;
empresasMarkers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < empresas.length; i++) {

            empresaMark = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: Number(empresas[i].Latitude), lng: Number(empresas[i].Longitude) },
                map: map,
                title: empresas[i].Nome,
                icon :'../Content/imagens/Icones/Markers/building-marker.png'
            });
             empresaMark.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<IMG BORDER="0" class="img img-rounded" style="height:55px;width:55px;margin-right:10px;object-fit: cover" ALIGN="Left" SRC='
                        + empresaMark.LinkFoto + '>'
                        + empresaMark.Nome
             });

        empresaMark.addListener('click', function() {
                empresaMark.info.open(map, empresaMark);
            });
            empresaMarkers.push(empresaMark);
        }
```

O erro ocorre na seguinte parte do código no objeto `empresaMark`:

```
empresaMark.addListener('click', function() {
                empresaMark.info.open(map, empresaMark);
            });
```

O erro é o seguinte :

> Closure on a variable in loop of outer scope

Eu andei lendo sobre `Closure` e vi algumas perguntas no `stackoverflow` mas não consegui entender completamente, e muito menos aplicar ao meu código, caso alguém consiga me explicar o que preciso fazer para arrumar esse código e a utilidade das `Closure` eu ficaria grato.

Algumas perguntas que eu vi:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

[Javascript infamous Loop issue? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

[How to make object in loop in js with external value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938178/how-to-make-object-in-loop-in-js-with-external-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96597/scope-e-iife-em-js/96620#96620) respondi uma pergunta parecida com a sua. Uma das soluções, inclusive, é a mesma.

O problema no seu código é que você sempre está acessando a variável empresaMarke do contexto em que seu click handler foi criado, esta variável, ao final da execução do loop, sempre apontará para o último marker **criado no loop**, e não aquele em que o handler foi criado.

Existem duas formas para resolver seu problema.

Uma é a seguinte(os detalhes estão no link que coloquei acima):

```
for (var i = 0; i < empresas.length; i++) {
  (function(empresa){
            var empresaMark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: Number(empresa.Latitude), lng: Number(empresa.Longitude) },
            map: map,
            title: empresa.Nome,
            icon :'../Content/imagens/Icones/Markers/building-marker.png'
        });
         empresaMark.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<IMG BORDER="0" class="img img-rounded" style="height:55px;width:55px;margin-right:10px;object-fit: cover" ALIGN="Left" SRC='
                    + empresaMark.LinkFoto + '>'
                    + empresaMark.Nome
         });

        empresaMark.addListener('click', function() {
            empresaMark.info.open(map, empresaMark);
        });
        empresaMarkers.push(empresaMark);
   }(empresas[i]))

}
```

A segunda seria fazer uma modificação nesse ponto do código:

```
 empresaMark.addListener('click', function() {
            empresaMark.info.open(map, empresaMark);
 });
```

para:

```
 empresaMark.addListener('click', function() {
      this.info.open(map, empresaMark);
 });
```

Levando em conta que o próprio marker é passado como contexto para o click handler.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado por explicação me ajudou muito.